# How do I efficiently create a TRIGGER which, on occasion, generates a VIEW?

Tags: sql, jdbc, triggers, oracle10g

On a small pre-registration database, I'm using the following SQL to generate a VIEW whenever a specific user name is given. I'm using this mainly to get a snapshot whenever a sysadmin suspects duplicate names are registering. This will be done rarely (atmost once per hour), so the database schema shouldn't be getting excessively big.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER upd_on_su_entry
    AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT
    ON PRE_REG_MEMBER
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.MEMBER_NAME  = 'SysAdmin Dup Tester' THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW mem_n AS SELECT :old.MEMBER_NAME, COUNT(:old.MEMBER_NAME) FROM MEMBER GROUP BY MEMBER_NAME';
    END IF;
END;
```

However, this appears to be a bloated, inefficient and erroneous way of working (according to my admin). Is there a fundamental error here ? Can I take an equivalent snapshot some other way?

I'm very new to SQL, so please bear with me.

Also, I want to be using the view as :

```
public void dups()throws Exception
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    jt.setText("Duplicate List at : "+ cal.getTime());
    try{
        rs=stat.executeQuery("select * from upd_on_su_entry");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            jt.append(rs.getString("MEMBER_NAME")+"\t");
            jt.append(rs.getString(2)+"\t");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.print("\n"+e);}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this trigger supposed to do?  It looks like it just redefines a view to have one row containing the user name in it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @therealmitchconnors Aargh, it seems I miscopied the query string. There was supposed to be a sys_refcursor in there to get multiple rows. The view would just verify that which users have multiple registrations. I'm sorry, got to update the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be some misunderstandings here.

1.) views are basically stored sql statements, not stored sql results, so your view will always display the data as it is at the point of querying the view.

2.) Never ever use DDL (create statements) and similar during normal processing of an application. Its just not the way databases are intended to work.

If you want a snapshot at a point in time, create a secondary table which contains all the columns of the original table plus a snapshot time stamp.

When ever you want to make a snapshot copy all the data you want from the original table into the snapshot table while adding the current time stamp.

Comment: I didn't get your first point, could you clarify ? And I expected, perhaps naively, that creating a multitude of views would have less overhead than creating duplicate tables. I was wrong there, then ?

Comment: If you select from a view, the select statement inside the view is executed in that moment, therefore views are just not suitable for your purpose. You could use materialized views, but you shouldn't except when you have performance issues

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you want something like this

```
SELECT MEMBER_NAME FROM PRE_REG_MEMBER
GROUP BY MEMBER_NAME HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This will return all members with more than one row in the table

Comment: This is useful, thank you. But, I actually want _all_ members at the time of snapshot - including legit ones, so the `COUNT(*)` function isn't necessary.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking... I thought you wanted a list of duplicate members?  Now you want a list of all members?  Isn't that what the table is?  You really should avoid defining a view in a trigger...

Comment: I'm sorry I can't explain what I'm trying to do : whenever the name `SysAdmin Dup Tester` is entered, I want to create a view that would show me the member name, and the number of duplicate (if any). Should I edit that into the question ?

Comment: Also, _I am_ looking for an alternate solution. The one I gave is _not_ a good one, as you can tell.

Comment: It sounds like you are treating the view like a table.  Views do not need to have rows added to them, as they do not store data.  A view is simply and SQL statement that transforms data stored in tables.  When we execute this SQL on the fly, it is just a statement, but when we want to store the SQL statement to the database for reuse, it is called a view.

Comment: I do have a _lot_ to learn, it seems. So I should do what @Jens suggested and create duplicate tables ?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is not duplicate views or tables, but just multiple rows in one table (this is the purpose of tables).  I strongly recommend you learn more about [the purpose of databases](http://www.db-class.org/course/auth/welcome) before you attempt to design one.

Comment: Hmm. My question, and understanding, was premature. I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Again, ask yourself "what am I trying to do"?

Don't focus on the technology. Do that after you have a clear idea of what your goal is.

If you are just trying to avoid duplicate registrations on your database, just search the users table and show an error if that username is already there.

Also, think of your datamodel carefully before going into the implementation details.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say. But I'm not just avoiding duplicate registration : I'm trying to keep a snapshot of who and when duplicate registrations were made. I admit, my implementation is messed up.

Comment: Then, just create a table like "REGISTRATION_LOG" and store all registrations there. Then you can easily find duplicate registrations with a query on that table. But I wonder *why* you want duplicate registrations on your site...

Comment: I _don't_, obviously, what I want is to keep a snapshot whenever the admin wants to, which would clearly show how many duplicates and non-duplicates were registered at that time. This is for some obscure security purpose, the reason of which is not known to me.